# trying to create a simple menu option selection - on click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**okay i have a simple menu options**; when a user clicks on one of the the menu items div of that category are shown on the screen. *(*all courses should by default display all divs).*

**What it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9voy.jpg**

**Example:** If clicked on FOREX menu, the divs related to forex with appear while other divs will disapear, **All Courses menu option will be default on click showing all the divs unless anothe is clicked.**

**My attempt:** all the divs have `display: none;`, im using a `switch` statement to find which div is clicked and changing to `display:block` to show.

**getting the error:**

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at n (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
>       at HTMLDivElement. (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4)

```js
/* COURSE SELECTION TOGGLE */
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery('.toggle-course-box-forex').toggleClass('show');
    
      switch(jQuery('toggle-course-box').click()) {
    
          case jQuery('#forex').click():
           jQuery("toggle-course-box-forex").css({"display": "block"});
              break;
          case jQuery('#stock').click():
           jQuery("toggle-course-box-stock").css({"display": "block"});
              break;
          default:
     }
    
    });
```

```css
    /* COURSE SELECTION TOGGLE ONLY*/
    .pointer-cursor:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    } 
    
    /* forex */
    /*.toggle-course-box-forex {
      display: none;
    } */
    .toggle-course-box-forex {
     display: none;
      transition: left 0.3s linear;
    }
    
    
    /* stock */
    .toggle-course-box-stock {
      display: none;
      transition: left 0.3s linear;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="course-body-container">
    <ul class="courses-menu course-content-home" id="course-selection-btn">
     <li class="course-item pointer-cursor" id="all-courses"><a>ALL COURSES</a></li>
     <li class="course-item pointer-cursor" id="degree"><a> DEGREES</a></li>
     <li class="course-item pointer-cursor" id="workshop"><a> WORSHOPS</a></li>
     <li class="course-item pointer-cursor" id="stock"><a>STOCK TRADER</a></li>
     <li class="course-item pointer-cursor" id="forex"><a>FOREX</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="course-prev-box">


     <div class="course-preview-category-1 toggle-course-box flex-item toggle-course-box-workshop">
      <img class="course-preview-img" src="img/course-icon.png">
      <p class="course-preview-headline" id="secondary-headline">“Success with Stocks in PSX” Workshop</p>
      <p class="course-preview-content" id="para-text">Experience the 2 day workshop for an introductory course on success with stocks in PSX</p><br>
      <a class="course-preview-btn" href="course-detail-template.html"> LEARN MORE</a>
      
     </div>
     <div class="course-preview-category-7 toggle-course-box flex-item toggle-course-box-stock">
      <img class="course-preview-img" src="img/course-icon.png">
      <p class="course-preview-headline"  id="secondary-headline">Art of Trading Stocks</p>
      <p class="course-preview-content" id="para-text">Welcome in my course “Art of Trading Stocks”. It is recommended for newbies and traders still not making profits in trading. This  course purely provides education for learning trading skills and is not an income advisory, by any means.</p><br>
      <a class="course-preview-btn" href="course-detail-template.html"> LEARN MORE</a>
      
     </div> 
     <div class="course-preview-category-3 toggle-course-box flex-item toggle-course-box-mba">
      <img class="course-preview-img" src="img/course-icon.png">
      <p class="course-preview-headline"  id="secondary-headline">MBA(major course) Equity market</p>
      <p class="course-preview-content" id="para-text">Our upcoming course on subject “Capital market” is aimed to be offered as major for MBA program is in collaboration with recognized universities in Karachi and soon will be launched in coming semester (subject to approval in time).</p><br>
      <a class="course-preview-btn" href="course-detail-template.html"> LEARN MORE</a>
      
     </div> 
     <div class="course-preview-category-4 toggle-course-box flex-item toggle-course-box-bba">
      <img class="course-preview-img" src="img/course-icon.png">
      <p class="course-preview-headline"  id="secondary-headline">BBA (major course)Capital market </p>
      <p class="course-preview-content" id="para-text">Our upcoming course on subject ” Capital market” is aimed to be offered as major for BBA program in collaboration with recognized universities in Karachi and soon will be launched in coming semester subject to approval in time. </p><br>
      <a class="course-preview-btn" href="course-detail-template.html"> LEARN MORE</a>
      
     </div> 
     <div class="course-preview-category-5 toggle-course-box flex-item toggle-course-box-stock">
      <img class="course-preview-img" src="img/course-icon.png">
      <p class="course-preview-headline"  id="secondary-headline">Managing Trading and Investment in Stocks</p>
      <p class="course-preview-content" id="para-text">This course is designed for beginners and intermediary level students to learn about PSX. </p><br>
      <a class="course-preview-btn" href="course-detail-template.html"> LEARN MORE</a>
      
     </div> 
     <div class="course-preview-category-6 toggle-course-box flex-item toggle-course-box-forex">
      <img class="course-preview-img" src="img/course-icon.png">
      <p class="course-preview-headline" id="secondary-headline">Introduction to Forex Trading</p>
      <p class="course-preview-content" id="para-text">Welcome in my course “Introduction to Forex Trading”. It is recommended for newbies and beginners still not making profits in Forex. This basic course purely provides education for learning trading skills and is not an income advisory, by any means.</p><br>
      <a class="course-preview-btn" href="course-detail-template.html"> LEARN MORE</a>
      
     </div> 
     <div class="course-preview-category-2 toggle-course-box flex-item toggle-course-box-forex">
      <img class="course-preview-img" src="img/course-icon.png">
      <p class="course-preview-headline"  id="secondary-headline">Becoming a Profitable Forex Trader</p>
      <p class="course-preview-content" id="para-text">Welcome to course “Becoming a profitable Forex Trader”. This comprehensive course purely provides education for learning and enhancing your trading skills and is not an income advisory, by any means. The entire course is designed with educational content carefully filtered what actually works.</p><br>
      <a class="course-preview-btn" href="course-detail-template.html"> LEARN MORE</a>
      
     </div> 
     <div class="course-preview-category-8 toggle-course-box flex-item toggle-course-box-stock">
      <img class="course-preview-img" src="img/course-icon.png">
      <p class="course-preview-headline"  id="secondary-headline">Introduction to technical analysis</p>
      <p class="course-preview-content" id="para-text">Welcome in my course “Introduction to Technical Analysis”. It is recommended for newbies and traders still not making profits in trading and they would like to learn technical analysis to sharpen their trading skills. This basic course purely provides education for learning trading skills and is not an income advisory, by any means.</p><br>
      <a class="course-preview-btn" href="course-detail-template.html"> LEARN MORE</a>
      
     </div>     
    </div>
    </div>
```

Not sure what is wrong with my approach? Alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you would use `switch`, so I made an alternative solution.

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle-course-box-forex').toggleClass('show');
  $('#forex').click(function() {
      $(".toggle-course-box").css({ "display": "none"});
      $(".toggle-course-box-forex").css({"display": "block"});
    });
    $('#stock').click(function() {
      $(".toggle-course-box").css({"display": "none"});
      $(".toggle-course-box-stock").css({"display": "block"});
    });
    $('#workshop').click(function() {
      $(".toggle-course-box").css({"display": "none"});
      $(".toggle-course-box-workshop").css({"display": "block"});
    });
    $('#all-courses').click(function() {
      $(".toggle-course-box").css({"display": "none"});
      $(".toggle-course-box-mba").css({"display": "block"});
    });
    $('#degree').click(function() {
      $(".toggle-course-box").css({"display": "none"});
      $(".toggle-course-box-bba").css({"display": "block"});
    });
});
```

```css
/* COURSE SELECTION TOGGLE ONLY*/

.pointer-cursor:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* forex */

.toggle-course-box{
  display: none;
}

.toggle-course-box-forex {
  display: none;
  transition: left 0.3s linear;
}


/* stock */

.toggle-course-box-stock {
  display: none;
  transition: left 0.3s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="course-body-container">
  <ul class="courses-menu course-content-home" id="course-selection-btn">
    <li class="course-item pointer-cursor" id="all-courses"><a>ALL COURSES</a></li>
    <li class="course-item pointer-cursor" id="degree"><a> DEGREES</a></li>
    <li class="course-item pointer-cursor" id="workshop"><a> WORSHOPS</a></li>
    <li class="course-item pointer-cursor" id="stock"><a>STOCK TRADER</a></li>
    <li class="course-item pointer-cursor" id="forex"><a>FOREX</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="course-prev-box">


    <div class="course-preview-category-1 toggle-course-box flex-item toggle-course-box-workshop">
      <img class="course-preview-img" src="img/course-icon.png">
      <p class="course-preview-headline" id="secondary-headline">“Success with Stocks in PSX” Workshop</p>
      <p class="course-preview-content" id="para-text">Experience the 2 day workshop for an introductory course on success with stocks in PSX</p><br>
      <a class="course-preview-btn" href="course-detail-template.html"> LEARN MORE</a>

    </div>
    <div class="course-preview-category-7 toggle-course-box flex-item toggle-course-box-stock">
      <img class="course-preview-img" src="img/course-icon.png">
      <p class="course-preview-headline" id="secondary-headline">Art of Trading Stocks</p>
      <p class="course-preview-content" id="para-text">Welcome in my course “Art of Trading Stocks”. It is recommended for newbies and traders still not making profits in trading. This course purely provides education for learning trading skills and is not an income advisory, by any means.</p><br>
      <a class="course-preview-btn" href="course-detail-template.html"> LEARN MORE</a>

    </div>
    <div class="course-preview-category-3 toggle-course-box flex-item toggle-course-box-mba">
      <img class="course-preview-img" src="img/course-icon.png">
      <p class="course-preview-headline" id="secondary-headline">MBA(major course) Equity market</p>
      <p class="course-preview-content" id="para-text">Our upcoming course on subject “Capital market” is aimed to be offered as major for MBA program is in collaboration with recognized universities in Karachi and soon will be launched in coming semester (subject to approval in time).</p><br>
      <a class="course-preview-btn" href="course-detail-template.html"> LEARN MORE</a>

    </div>
    <div class="course-preview-category-4 toggle-course-box flex-item toggle-course-box-bba">
      <img class="course-preview-img" src="img/course-icon.png">
      <p class="course-preview-headline" id="secondary-headline">BBA (major course)Capital market </p>
      <p class="course-preview-content" id="para-text">Our upcoming course on subject ” Capital market” is aimed to be offered as major for BBA program in collaboration with recognized universities in Karachi and soon will be launched in coming semester subject to approval in time. </p><br>
      <a class="course-preview-btn" href="course-detail-template.html"> LEARN MORE</a>

    </div>
    <div class="course-preview-category-5 toggle-course-box flex-item toggle-course-box-stock">
      <img class="course-preview-img" src="img/course-icon.png">
      <p class="course-preview-headline" id="secondary-headline">Managing Trading and Investment in Stocks</p>
      <p class="course-preview-content" id="para-text">This course is designed for beginners and intermediary level students to learn about PSX. </p><br>
      <a class="course-preview-btn" href="course-detail-template.html"> LEARN MORE</a>

    </div>
    <div class="course-preview-category-6 toggle-course-box flex-item toggle-course-box-forex">
      <img class="course-preview-img" src="img/course-icon.png">
      <p class="course-preview-headline" id="secondary-headline">Introduction to Forex Trading</p>
      <p class="course-preview-content" id="para-text">Welcome in my course “Introduction to Forex Trading”. It is recommended for newbies and beginners still not making profits in Forex. This basic course purely provides education for learning trading skills and is not an income advisory, by any means.</p><br>
      <a class="course-preview-btn" href="course-detail-template.html"> LEARN MORE</a>

    </div>
    <div class="course-preview-category-2 toggle-course-box flex-item toggle-course-box-forex">
      <img class="course-preview-img" src="img/course-icon.png">
      <p class="course-preview-headline" id="secondary-headline">Becoming a Profitable Forex Trader</p>
      <p class="course-preview-content" id="para-text">Welcome to course “Becoming a profitable Forex Trader”. This comprehensive course purely provides education for learning and enhancing your trading skills and is not an income advisory, by any means. The entire course is designed with educational
        content carefully filtered what actually works.</p><br>
      <a class="course-preview-btn" href="course-detail-template.html"> LEARN MORE</a>

    </div>
    <div class="course-preview-category-8 toggle-course-box flex-item toggle-course-box-stock">
      <img class="course-preview-img" src="img/course-icon.png">
      <p class="course-preview-headline" id="secondary-headline">Introduction to technical analysis</p>
      <p class="course-preview-content" id="para-text">Welcome in my course “Introduction to Technical Analysis”. It is recommended for newbies and traders still not making profits in trading and they would like to learn technical analysis to sharpen their trading skills. This basic course purely provides
        education for learning trading skills and is not an income advisory, by any means.</p><br>
      <a class="course-preview-btn" href="course-detail-template.html"> LEARN MORE</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: $('.toggle-course-box-forex').toggleClass('show');
what is this line for?

Comment: @Shaz , its adds and removes the show class on each click.

Comment: Ah, but is there a way to have default all courses menu showing with all the divs by default?

Comment: what do you mean by default? when the first page is loaded?